# What happened to my MathOverflow account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, moderation, login, deleted-accounts

I posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453698/512645) from my account two days ago. Now suddenly, I saw I don't have an account any longer. I tried to log in and Overflow created a new account. Can someone please shed some light on what happened? I want to get my old account back.

Please note that [my MSE account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1096489/dumbest-person-on-earth) is still unharmed, and so are all other accounts on other StackExchange sites. However, MathOverflow just seems to have vanished into thin air.

Comment: Perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:deleted-accounts]) would be suitable here. I am not sure whether the tag ([meta-tag:policy]) is really needed.

Comment: "StackOverflow"? Do you mean, MathOverflow?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, edited.

Comment: @MartinSleziak done